# show text instead of ID of foreign key in gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

I'm binding a gridview by code, the problem I have is that one of the columns displayed is a foreign key to another table, thus the integer value is displayed. Is there maybe a posible way to display the text value of that foreign key?

This is what I have done:

```
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Customer, ContactPerson, Model, SerialNo, Status, Type, Value, InvoiceNo" &
                                  " FROM BackBillCustomer WHERE Status = 'Open'", cn)
        cn.Open()
            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If rs.HasRows Then
                Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                rs.Close()
                adp.Fill(ds, "CustMeter")
                gvMeter.AllowPaging = True
                gvMeter.PageSize = (10)
                gvMeter.DataSource = ds
                gvMeter.DataBind()

                gvMeter.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal")
            Else
                rs.Close()
```

The "Type" column is the foreign key. In this table there are only two rows ID and Type. How can I display Type instead of the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query...

```
SELECT a.ID, Customer, ContactPerson, Model, SerialNo, Status, b.Type, Value, InvoiceNo
     FROM BackBillCustomer a inner join ForegnKeyTableName b  on a.Type=B.id and Status = 'Open'
```